# Find files by given pattern and grep for whole word count matching the search string pattern and ignoring some pattern and print along with file name

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, grep

**Requirement** : I need to search whole words matching '***xceptions***' and count individual word occurrence and print file name where it is found, also ignore lines where '**throws**' string is present but not print date pattern used for searching the lines.

I can only use ' *find, grep, zgrep, awk, cut* ' commands

**Example**: File name "server.log" containing below text for different dates.

```
2017-12-08 00:39:44,453 Some lengthier string.with.javaExceptionString with more data here
2017-12-08 00:39:44,453 Some lengthier string.with.javaExceptionString with more data here
2017-12-09 00:39:44,453 Some more string.with.ContextServiceException some thing here
2017-12-09 00:40:44,453 Some more string.with.ContextServiceException junk values
2017-12-09 00:39:44,453 Some more java.net.MalformedURLException with more data here
2017-12-09 00:39:44,453 function () throws genericException which should not be grepped
2017-12-10 11:11:12,123 function () throws MalformedURLException which should not be grepped
2017-12-10 09:09:12,123 function () throws ContextServiceException which should not be grepped
2017-12-10 09:09:12,123 some oracle error ORA-10001 not grepped
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 some oracle error ORA-99999 should be counted
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 another oracle error ORA-20002 with java error ArrayOutOfBoundException and more...
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 java error ArrayOutOfBoundException and another oracle error ORA-20002  and more...
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 multiple errors line IOException and NullPointerException, RunTimeException and many more
```

Sample command which prints all the word count except date match :

```
find /tmp/ -name "*log*" -exec zgrep -HPo "(\b\w*xception|ORA-\w*\b)" {} + 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq -c
```

**Current Output**:

```
2 /tmp/server.log:ArrayOutOfBoundException
3 /tmp/server.log:ContextServiceException
1 /tmp/server.log:IOException
2 /tmp/server.log:MalformedURLException
1 /tmp/server.log:NullPointerException
1 /tmp/server.log:ORA-10001
2 /tmp/server.log:ORA-20002
1 /tmp/server.log:ORA-99999
1 /tmp/server.log:RunTimeException
1 /tmp/server.log:genericException
2 /tmp/server.log:javaExceptionString
```

Need your help in writing single line command in unix using 'find, grep, awk, cut' but not perl or sed Expected Output if I filter only for 2017-12-09 (need command here)

**Expected Output** where it has filtered only **2017-12-09** logs and ignored lines with '**throws**'

```
2 /tmp/server.log:ArrayOutOfBoundException
2 /tmp/server.log:ContextServiceException
1 /tmp/server.log:IOException
1 /tmp/server.log:MalformedURLException
1 /tmp/server.log:NullPointerException
2 /tmp/server.log:ORA-20002
1 /tmp/server.log:ORA-99999
1 /tmp/server.log:RunTimeException
```

*zgrep* is used so that if there are any gzip file it needs to search in those file as well.

Comment: I will be having files with pattern like server.log.2017-12-01.gz, server.log.2017-12-09 and server.log

Comment: 1) No need to use `find` command if you are processing only one single file `single.log` ; 2) what your `|ORA` subpattern for? 3) Should the command accept an arbitrary date to filter out OR filter by current date? Answer this questions beforehand

Comment: |ORA will be another sub pattern match, like excpeption to get the whole ORA error like ORA-20001

Comment: I will be dynamically creating the date pattern based on user requirement, for example I can search of 1st Dec log entries by changing it to 2017-12-01

Comment: @janos, it is restricted by System Admini, only few set of commands are allowed to run on the servers. I can pipe out the results using | xargs as well, as long as the expected result is achieved (in a single line command)

Comment: awk version is 4.0.2

Comment: So you can use `awk` but not `sed`??

Comment: Yes, Sed they think it can alter main files when wrongly used, but awk will never modify the source file.

Comment: `awk` can also do in place editing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly,
you are looking two make two changes:

- Exclude lines that contain "throws"
- Exclude lines that don't start with "2017-12-09 "

You could use a `zgrep` to match the lines that you want (start with "2017-12-09 " and contain "xception"),
and then an `awk` to exclude the lines that you don't want (contains "throws"),
and exclude parts of the lines that you don't want (text between filename and the exception name):

```
find ... -exec zgrep -HE '^2017-12-09.*(xception|ORA-)' {} + \
| awk '!/throws/ { print gensub(/^([^:]+:).*\<(\w+xception\w*|ORA-\w+).*/, "\\1\\2", $0) }' \
| sort | uniq -c
```

This should work with the GNU implementation of `awk`.

After your further clarification,
you want to turn a line like this:

> ```
> /tmp/server.log:2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 another oracle error ORA-20002 with java error ArrayOutOfBoundException and more...
> ```

To lines like this:

```
/tmp/server.log:ORA-20002
/tmp/server.log:ArrayOutOfBoundException
```

That's possible, using a different tool of `awk`, the `match` function,
which returns the starting position of a match, and 0 when there are no more matches. We can call it repeatedly, with appropriately modified parameters, as long as there are matches, and print the output as we go:

```
find ... -exec zgrep -HE '^2017-12-09.*(xception|ORA-)' {} + \
| awk -F: '!/throws/ { s = $0; while (match(s, /\w+xception\w*|ORA-\w+/)) { print $1 ":" substr(s, RSTART, RLENGTH); s = substr(s, RSTART + RLENGTH + 1); }}' \
| sort | uniq -c
```

Comment: Your understanding is correct,I tried this option of two greps by using Pipes, in that case I will not be able to print the file name matched, in that case it was printing "Standard Input"

Comment: @ChandreGowda I see, I overlooked some of your requirements. I fixed now, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the command, it partially worked, it is not identifying ORA content in the following line where both ORA and Exception string is found. But is working fine if the line contains only ORA or only xception string
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 some Oracle Exception ORA-20002 with error ContextServiceException java string...

Comment: @ChandreGowda you have not included such example input and expected output. Without that I cannot guess how exactly you want it. You should have included important corner cases in your question.

Comment: I'm extremely sorry for that, another example mentioned below where there is different exceptions in a single line, only last one is considered 
2017-12-09 09:09:12,123 multiple errors line ioExcption and NullPointerException

Comment: @ChandreGowda once again, you are adding more hidden requirements that were not present in the posted question. For one thing, that's not fair. For another, you still haven't explained what the expected output should be in these corner cases, so it's impossible to answer any of these questions. I could take a guess, sure, but if I guess wrong, you might respond with "that's not how I wanted it", and my work will be for nothing.

Comment: Appreciate your help, added few more sample source file line and expected output